Ubuntu OS reinstall
I want to do a ubuntu OS installation on multiple laptops for the users sitting in different locations using automated scripts may be with ansible, so as to minimise the work and make the laptop build faster.
Need suggestions on it.

How many systems? And are they all identical? For only a few, you can do a standard install & restore, just like when your system crashes & you restore from your backup. I also did same to external SSD which I have booted on 3 systems, One from 2006, 2017 and 2021. But all Intel & no proprietary drivers which complicate installs.

Same systems. So if i create a central node and generate ssh keys and copy them to the other machines with ansible script, so will that work?

Or we have to configure the dhcp server and tftp server on control node and then create playbooks? Please suggest which option to go for automating ubuntu installation.
